# Showing that $F(k,x) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^n)$ is not a secure PRF

Tags: pseudo-random-function

Let $X = \{0, 1\}^n$. Given a PRF $F : X \times X \rightarrow X$, define

$$H(k, x) = F(k,x) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^n).$$

I *think* this is insecure, since $H(k, x) = H(k, \bar{x})$ for all $x \in X$, where the bar notation denotes the bitwise not.

However, I was able to come up with the following innocent-looking proof that $H$ is a PRF.

---

Suppose that $H$ is insecure. Then there is an efficient adversary $A$ that wins the PRF game against $H$ with non-negligible advantage. We construct an efficient adversary $B$ for $F$ as follows:

1. $B$ invokes $A$ and receives queries $x_1, \dots, x_q$.
2. $B$ sends $2q$ queries, by sending $x_i$ and $\bar{x_i}$ for $i = 1, \dots, q$.
3. The PRF challenger for $F$ computes and returns $y_i = f(x_i)$, $y_i' = f(\bar{x_i})$.

   - In experiment $0$, $f = F(k, \cdot)$.
   - In experiment $1$, $f$ is a truly random function $X \rightarrow X$.
4. $B$ then computes $y_i \oplus y_i'$ and returns it to $A$.

   - In experiment $0$, $A$ would receive $H(k, x_i)$.
   - In experiment $1$, $A$ would receive a random bit string. $(*)$
5. $A$ computes and returns a bit $b'$, which $B$ receives and returns $b'$ as the final result.

Let $\Pr[W_b^C]$ be the event that an adversary $C$ returns $1$ in experiment $b$.
Then $\Pr[W_0^A] = \Pr[W_0^B]$ by construction, and $\Pr[W_1^A] = \Pr[W_1^B]$ since the XOR of two random strings is also random. Thus $B$ also has non-negligible advantage, so $F$ is insecure, contradicting the assumption.

---

What's wrong in this proof? I think the part $(*)$ and arguing that $\Pr[W_1^A] = \Pr[W_1^B]$ feels a bit fishy, but I learned that XORing two random strings also gives a random string, so it seems OK. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have actually proposed an adversary A against H: it makes two queries (for example the all-zero and the all-one bit strings). What goes wrong in your reduction when applying it to this adversary A?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but $A$ is already an adversary against $H$ in the assumption of the proof, I didn't construct anything for $H$. I understand that the insecurity of $H$ can be shown directly by querying $0^n$ and $1^n$, but I don't understand what goes wrong in the reduction.

Comment: If your reduction works, it works in particular for any adversary A, and you have one candidate at hand for it, so you can look at what it does in this special case, which should help see where the reasoning goes wrong.

Comment: Umm I meditated this for a while now, so if $A$ queries $0^n$ and $1^n$, it will receive (from $B$) two equal results in experiment 0, and two random strings in experiment 1. I still don't see what goes wrong. Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: B receives from A two queries on $x_1 = 0^n$ and $x_2 = 1^n$. However, B itself, per your construction, makes four queries, on $x_1, \bar{x}_1, x_2, \bar{x}_2$. I claim that even in experiment 1, it won't receive independently random responses to those four queries. In fact, the responses $y_1\oplus y'_1$ and $y_2\oplus y'_2$ are clearly equal in *both* experiments. Does that clarify things enough?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I should have checked carefully...